# How to setup a new non profit instance without npsp?

Tags: setup, nonprofit-starter-pack, instance

When I go to salesforce.org, I don't see where to just create a non-profit instance without using the npsp? Is this doable? if so, where to click?

Also, I only see options to use Lightning. What if I just want classic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Salesforce there are no "non-profit orgs" but you can use Sales Cloud with the NPSP package. Now all new orgs come in lightning and you cannot revert them to classic, but NPSP is lightning ready.

Answer (score 0):

The license donations to nonprofits is called the Power of Us Program, it's a little hard to find on the .org website.  On the [Get Started page](http://www.salesforce.org/nonprofit/get-started/) you can create an instance without the NPSP, but Torsen is right that it is enabled for Lightning.